# SQL Server 2008 R2: Only get NULL when using XQuery (.value) to query into XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

My table is called `Table_1` with 2 columns:

```
id (int) and myxml (xml)
```

I attached the xml snapshot I am working with below.
(This xml corresponded to `id = 1`)

The problem I have is that I only get NULL when using XQuery (.value) to query into this XML

This is the code I wrote:

```
SELECT myXml.value('(Archivebatch/Cr/Modifcltn/Modif)[2]/@modiftype','int')
 from Table_1 where id = 1
```

I only get NULL no matter what I tried to query out of the xml
I have also try including namespace which doesn't help (still only return NULL)

**EDIT**: I tried to include namespace by:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS ns) 
select myXml.value(' 
(/ns:Archivebatch/ns:Cr/ns:Modifcltn/ns:Modif)[2]/@modiftype','int') 
from dbo.table_1 where id = 1
```

[image]

Comment: Do not attach code as links/pictures. The question will become incomplete if link changes or is broken. Always include code and related information in the question itself.

Comment: Copy-paste-ing XML to the question doesn't cost much effort and is valuable for people to reproduce the problem. Also how did you try to include namespace in the query?

Comment: Sorry regarding the image. I have update my post to reflect the namespace in the query. @har07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace that matter for this particular query is the default namespace defined here :

```
xmlns="SIMATIC_BATCH_V8_1_0"
```

so you should've registered `ns` prefix to point to the above namespace URI, or you can register default namespace using `;WITH XMLNAMESPACES` and omit prefixes from the xquery as it becomes default now  :

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'SIMATIC_BATCH_V8_1_0')
select myXml.value('(/Archivebatch/Cr/Modifcltn/Modif)[2]/@modiftype','int') 
from dbo.table_1 where id = 1
```

Comment: I had spent some time searching through the internet and Stackoverflow, how come sometime there's the namespace included (as you have done) and sometime there isn't (like the first code I wrote)? Does the namespace have to always be included? Thanks again!!

Comment: @MaytasMonsereenusorn That depends on the XML you're dealing with. If your XML has namespace, then you should use `;WITH XMLNAMESPACES` somehow, if the XML has not then you can do it like the first code you wrote